# Arrange DIVs in the right position

Tags: html, css

I'm having huge problems trying to arrage my DIVs, as I found that this thing is not as simple as it seems, just put a DIV and inside that DIV another 2 and you're done. The image bellow shows how I would want my page to be structured:
sur1.
surf2: surfleft, surfright. surf3. surf4 Where . means another line and , means that DIVs should be one next to another.
And also can't center that image vertical and horizontall middle on surfright from surf 2 parent.

```css
@font-face 
{
    font-family: FONT;
    src: url(Montserrat-Regular.ttf);
}

p.title1
{
 font-size: 2.5em;
 margin: 0;
}

p.title2
{
 font-size: 3em;
}

.i1
{
 height: 400px;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 150px;
 
}

div.surf1
{

 display: block;
 background-image: url("surf1.jpg");
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 600px;
}

div.surf2 {
    width: fit-content;
    position:absolute;
    background: #41c3ac;
    height: 600px;
}


div.surfleft {
    float:left;
    display: block;
    width: 45%;
    padding-top: 80px;
    height: 600px;
 background: #8C78B1;
 }

div.surfright {
 float: right;
 background: #ff6b57;
 }

div.surf3
{
 background: #ff6b57;
 height: 600px;
}

div.surf4
{
 background: #8C78B1;
 height: 600px;
}

div.text1
{
 padding-top: 100px;
 color: white;
 text-align:center;
 font-size: 2.5em;
}

div.button
{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 15%;
 padding: 8px;
 border: 2px solid;
 border-color: #e7dd84;
 background-color: rgba(236,229,167,0.2);
 color: #e7dd84;
 transition: 0.35s;

}
div.button:hover
{
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 border-color: white;
 transition: 0.35s;
}

body
{
 margin: 0;
 font-family: FONT;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<div class="surf1">
 <div class="text1">
  <b>Welcome to smartlearning.com, <br>the place where you can <br>learn and practice English</b>
 </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br>
 <div class="button">
  Go to site
 </div>
</div>
<div class="surf2">
 <div class="surfleft">
     <p class="title1">Interractive games</p>
         <ul style="font-size: 1.5em">
         <li>We have different types of games you can play, testing your abilities to recognise objects, multiple choise exercices and also putting you to the test of spotting mistakes.</li>
            <li>Those games are designed to help you learn and practice english by combining fun with hard-working.</li>   
          </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="surfright">
      <img  src="console.png" alt="404 Image not Found" height="400px">
     </div>
</div>
<div class="surf3"></div>
<div class="surf4"></div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: And if you try with flexbox. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I wouldn't roll your own styling for this. I would use bootstrap or another common framework. The reason being alot of your problems are already solved using these frameworks, and they are designed by people much smarter than you or I.

Comment: More experienced I would rather say, being much smarter means having equal knowledge and use it better than others. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that you may use correct width values to have fine edges in your design.

```css
div.surf1
{
 display: block;
 background-color: #cdcdcd;
 height: 100px;
}

div.surf2 {
    background: #41c3ac;
    height: 100px;
}

div.surfleft {
    float:left;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
 background: #8C78B1;
 }

div.surfright {
 float: right;
    width: 50%
 background: #ff6b57;
 }

div.surf3
{
 background: #ff6b57;
 height: 100px;
}

div.surf4
{
 background: #8C78B1;
 height: 100px;
}

body
{
 margin: 0;
 font-family: FONT;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="surf1">
 <div class="text1">Surf 1</div>
</div>
<div class="surf2">
 <div class="surfleft">Surf left</div>
     <div class="surfright">Surf right</div>
</div>
<div class="surf3">Surf 3</div>
<div class="surf4">Surf 4</div>
```

Comment: This also did the trick with centering the image within the DIV. I appreciate your help!